# What are some good open source text editors on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, text-editor, open-source

I just recently switched from Windows and I must say that as much as I'm satisfied with the whole OS, I'm disappointed by the text editors so far (I've tried [TextMate](http://macromates.com) and [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/)). So I figured I would check specifically into **open source** editors.

I'm currently checking out [MacVim](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim), but are there any other good, maintained text editors for OS X?

Comment: You do realize that most of what makes TextMate great in the eyes of its users is, in fact, open source?

Comment: I do, but they are things specifically in TextMate's core functionality (key bindings, project management, for example) that I don't like and that I've been unable to adapt to my workflow, even with plugins.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! "Better", "best", and "good" will be different for everybody. We can't tell you what application to use only based on the criteria "better than x" or "the best" or "good." Please ask again with specific requirements for the app (detailed feature set, where you want it to be strong, etc). Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanGreenstein Thanks. Would "Is there an open source text editor for Mac OS X Lion that's actively in development and has a nice Lion-like UI" work? Unfortunately, I think the answer is no :(

Comment: @julien_c That's a good start, but see if you can think of a few more 'killer features' that you want to see.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) that is a version of Emacs that has been customised to be more OSX like.

Apple supplies the source for TextEdit as an example with Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

[emacs for osx](http://emacsformacosx.com/) is by far my favorite.

But it depends a lot on what you edit. [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) and [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) are both IDEs but have nice support for many kinds of files. Maybe also [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) is worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

**[TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/)**

TextWrangler is the “little brother” to BBEdit, leading professional HTML and text editor for the Macintosh.

[image]

Comment: It is not open source just for no cost

Comment: I like to use the explanations: "free as in beer" and "free as in speech".

Comment: and would behave like BBedit which the OP said he did not want

Comment: @gentmail and I have no idea what they mean - I do understand what GNU is doing I just do not understand that tagline

Comment: Yeah, the open source part is important to me (if I'm going to live 10 hours a day in my text editor I want to be able to improve little things myself if I need to).

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite is a free one (where you can also donate for a fuller version) and it is also a beautifully designed/ distraction free editor: [OmmWriter](http://www.ommwriter.com/).

However the best thing possible if you are looking for something with the most functionality and the best compatibility cross-platform would be [NeoOffice](http://www.neooffice.org).

Answer (score 0):

## [Gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/)

It's not as functional as the version for Linux, but it is open source.
Also, it tends to crash a lot in lion...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Smultron 3.5.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smultron/files/smultron/)

This is the latest version of smultron which is open source. This version does not work on Lion!

The newer version of smultron is sold [via the App Store](http://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZContentLink.woa/wa/link?path=mac%2fpeterborgapps) and proprietary. Smultron 4 does work in lion.